# How to set a valid value with 1s resolution into a datetime-local with js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a datetime-local to the current date/time by pressing the "now" button. Pressing the button, the input control shows the correct time but also a constraint failure which says that I should set the next valid time which is somewhere around the time I just set. What am I doing wrong? The message appears on Chrome/Firefox/Edge, so it must be something in my code. (Depending on your browser, you have to hover over the input field after pressing "now" to see the error, Edge shows it directly)

```js
function timestampToDatetimeInputString(timestamp) {
  const date = new Date((timestamp + _getTimeZoneOffsetInMs()));
  // slice(0, 19) includes seconds
  dd = date.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
  return dd;
}

function _getTimeZoneOffsetInMs() {
  return new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -60 * 1000;
}

function fillForm() {
  document.forms.timeform.dt.value = timestampToDatetimeInputString(Date.now());
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/goform/settime" name="timeform">
  <input type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="dt" value="2021-11-26T10:07:11" max="2099-12-31T23:59:59" min="2000-01-01T00:00:00">
  <button onclick="fillForm()">Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - input requires the attribute "step=1" if I want to set the time in seconds precision. Funny how long one can stare at something and miss the (non-)obvious. (( Meta question: Should I delete the question completely or is it relevant enough to keep it? ))